# Puppeteer's page.cookies() not retrieving all cookies shown in the Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Using puppeteer, I am trying to retrieve all cookies for a specific web site (i.e. `https://google.com`) from Node.js.

My code is:

```
// Launch browser and open a new page
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage'] });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
var cookies = await page.cookies();
console.log(cookies);
await browser.close();
```

It only retrieves 2 cookies, named `1P_JAR` and `NID`. However, when I open the Chrome Dev tools, it shows a lot more.

I tried using the Chrome Dev Tools directly instead of puppeteer but I am getting the same results.

Is there another function I should call? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the "application" panel in the dev tools with cookies opened (pixelize the cookie values). Make sure page loading with all async tasks completed before trying to programmatically get cookies. The docs say "If no URLs are specified, this method returns cookies for the current page URL." - this might exclude cookies set for "www.google.com" or ".google.com" (regarding to your page URL "google.com").

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `page.cookies()` call only gets cookies that are available to JavaScript applications inside the browser, and not the ones marked `httpOnly`, which you see in the Chrome DevTools. The solution is to ask for all available cookies through the Devtools protocol and then filter for the site you're interested in.

```
var data = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with typescript unfortunately since _client is private

Answer (score 14):

You can utilise [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) -> [getAllCookies](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getAllCookies)
To get all browser cookies, regardless of any flags.

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
const cookies = (await client.send('Network.getAllCookies')).cookies;
```

This will also play nice with typescript and tslint since something like

```js
const cookies = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');
```

Will raise an error `TS2341: Property '_client' is private and only accessible within class 'Page'.`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @try-catch-finally. I got it resolved and it was a simple rookie mistake. 
I was comparing cookies in my own Google Chrome instance with the Puppeteer instance. However, in my instance, I was logged in to my Google account and Puppeteer (obviously) was not.
Google uses 2 cookies when you are NOT logged in and 12 when you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Playwright in place of Puppeteer, httponly cookies are readily accessible:

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright')
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch()
    const context = await browser.newContext()
    const page = await context.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://google.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' })
    let allCookies = await context.cookies()
    console.log (allCookies)
})();
```

returns:

```
[
  {
    sameSite: 'None',
    name: '1P_JAR',
    value: '2021-01-27-19',
    domain: '.google.com',
    path: '/',
    expires: 1614369040.389115,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: true
  },
  {
    sameSite: 'None',
    name: 'NID',
    value: '208=VXtmbaUL...',
    domain: '.google.com',
    path: '/',
    expires: 1627588239.572781,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
]
```

Comment: I see that this behavior is also in Puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

Just use it `await page.goto('https://google.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })`. And you can get all the cookies related.